# What is the best way to store a large amount of photos in an app?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, parse-platform

I'm talking 7,500+ images. The user needs to be able to access about 150 at a time, almost instantly.

I currently have them all saved as PFFiles on Parse.com, but retrieving them is VERY slow and buggy.

My thought is to store all of them locally on the device, but that would cause my app to be about 1GB in size. It may be something I'm willing to do, considering the nature of the app, but does anybody know of anything better?

My code for populating `UICollectionViewCells` with PFFiles is here:

```
var images = [PFFile]()

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: CardsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardsCollectionViewCell
    images[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            cell.cardsImg.image = image
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you use thumbnails? A user can't look at 150 full-res images at a time: ergo, you don't need to display 150 full-res photos instantly.

Answer (score 0):

As @rghome says, thumbnails could be an interesting way of doing for the size of the app.

If you really want to have them in the app and retrieve them quickly, I would use Realm ([realm.io](http://realm.io)) because they have a database which is easy to use and that retrieves data really fast.

If you want to keep your high-res images in the cloud for the size of the app, reducing the size of them in the app (thumbnails) can be a good way but I'm not a fan of his way.